# MongoDB - DeleteMany with returned ids

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to delete many entities from a mongo collection in a way that I will know deleted ids after all?

DeleteMany returns:

`{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 10 }`

FindOneAndDelete returns entity, but there is no way to delete many and to determine deleted ids.